# Unable to Render Django Template using Method

Tags: python, html, django

I created a function called getData in effort to cut down 4 nested "if" statement inside my userInfo method.  The result was devastating.  I'm being humiliated by the fact that the page didn't proceed to my successful.html template.  If I move everything inside getData method back to the userInfo function, everything return to normal.  Is there a trick to making it work so I can restore my shame?

**views.py**

```
def userInfo (request):

    # Set maximum to avoid default of 1000 forms.
    UserFormSet = formset_factory (UserForm, formset = BaseUserFormSet, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        formset = UserFormSet (request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid ():
            location = request.POST ['site']
            data = formset.cleaned_data
            getData (request, data, location)    # ====> Created a function to cut down nested if statement    
    else:
        formset = UserFormSet ()
...


def getData (request, data, location):

    validUser = []
    for form in data:
        username = form.get ('user_name')
        userID = form.get ('user_ID')

        if username and userID:
            n = register (username, userID, location)
            if n.checkDataBase ():
                validUser.append (username)
    if validUser:
        context = {'validUser': validUser}
        return render (request, 'userform/success.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Successfully Added</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>User Information:</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for user in validUser %}
            <li>{{ user }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'adduser' %}">Add more users</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you change your `getData()` to:

```
if validUser:
        context = {'validUser': validUser}
        return request, 'userform/success.html', context
```

and your `userInfo()` to:

```
if formset.is_valid ():
            location = request.POST ['site']
            data = formset.cleaned_data
            request, template, context = getData (request, data, location)    # ====> Created a function to cut down nested if statement
            return render (request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return getData (request, data, location)
```

(add `return` statement).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but that didn't do it.

Comment: Are you entering valid user data? I mean, does it reach ```return render (request, 'userform/success.html', context)``` in your getData? I don't see what should happen if user data is invalid, perhaps you should add this scenario in your getData(). Anyways, userInfo() must return HttpResponse instance that is returned by your getData(). So, my ```return``` statement is needed. If you tell me what's happening instead of desired result I may help you more... thanks.